# Overload Operator `[ ]` and ':'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, slice

I'm trying to implement a string function in C++, so it can operate as in Python.

For example, in Python you can code like,

```
str = "filename.ext"
bits_0 = str[1:3]
bits_1 = str[-1:]
```

One thing to overload is operator `[]`, but how to overload operator `:` in this case?

Comment: You can overload operators, but you cannot change their syntax. Since `[:]` is not a syntactically valid construct in C++, you won't be able to replicate the Python syntax exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:` is [not an operator in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B). It's only part of the scope resolution operator `::` or the ternary operator `?:`. Since it's not an operator, it can't be overloaded.

Editorial note: if you want to use Python, use Python.

Comment: I’d generally agree with your editorial note but there’s fundamentally nothing wrong with emulating convenient syntactic sugar in other languages. Having an array slice operator in particular would be nice.

Comment: The 'editorial note' is wrong and not applicable. The question describes the functionality he is looking for by an example in another language. It never says that he wants to use Python. He specifically states that he's using C++

Answer (score 5):

There is no `operator:` in C++. Thus you just cannot "overload" it.

Answer (score 0):

Colon that is ":" is not an operator.
The colon (:) in C++ is an operator that essentially invokes something called an initialization list. The initialization list can be used for things such as:

i) Calling the base class constructor

ii) Initializing member variables before the body of constructor executes.

One example where you may have seen the colon being used is to identify class access specifiers. For example:

private:

int x;

int y;